# How to set a Qt application to use the actual environment variables of a unix-like system?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, widget, environment-variables

I'm creating a Qt gui application using a library which searches the PATH environment variable for certain executables, namely compilers, make and cmake.
The problem is that std::getenv("PATH") returns something different in the gui and certain executables are missed. I've tried to use the QProcessEnvironment class to the set the PATH, however, the same problem arises. I can set it to specific paths in my machine but it would be great if it could get the PATH of any machine the application is deployed to.
Strangely if I start the gui using the command-line, everything works out fine! Although I find it unreasonable to ask users to open the gui using the command line.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you looked at the QStandardPaths Class?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately the QStandardPaths class wouldn't show some of the "unixy" paths like /usr/local/bin or /usr/local/opt, nor any custom paths added by the user. For the moment I've a workaround by providing a cmake generated script along with the app, the script basically runs the app from the terminal. It's inconvenient but I can't think of anything else!

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but what you see is expected. Application started from terminal can have different environmental variables than the one started as standalone GUI. That's because these are two different environments.

Comment: If your GUI application depends on other executables then I wouldn't hide the finding of executables to users. I mean let user configure this in a dialog and store this configuration in something like an ini or config file. So, the user has control over what your GUI app. does internally. Additionally, you may use your existing search functions to propose default settings for that dialog. And, you may open the dialog only if you detect that configuration is not yet done. (For the case, where a central administration installs your app on many work places, they may automate the configuration...

Comment: ...by writing an extra app. or script to create the proper config files. In this case, the user should never be bothered with this configuration dialog.)

Comment: Btw. _Unfortunately the QStandardPaths class wouldn't show some of the "unixy" paths_ Yeah, that's by intention. [`QStandardPaths`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#details) provides a portable way to access certain valuable paths which are on every supported OS/platform available somehow (like e.g. user directory or user config directory) but is accessed on any OS/platform with different functions. It was surely not intended to reflect the whole environment on any platform. For this: [`QStringList QProcess::systemEnvironment()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#systemEnvironment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with Qt. You've set the PATH using shell initialization scripts and such, in your own user folder. It'd be a terribly bad idea for the graphical shell to use that path, as a mistake in your shell profile would potentially make the entire desktop non-functional. Of course it works from the command line, since your shell profiles take effect then.

You could, as a user configuration option, extract the shell PATH by running the equivalent of user's `$SHELL -c 'echo $PATH'`, and processing the result.

Otherwise, you'll have to defer to what's customary on the platform, and consult package managers if needed. Different package systems tend to install these tools in different directories, but there is just a few common ones. I presume it'd be enough to cover Ubuntu, RedHat, macports and homebrew, and make sure that you check in "pure" FHS (Filesystem Hierarchy Standard) locations as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did try QProcess::start("/bin/bash -c \"echo $PATH\"") and reading the output but it's the same. I can't understand how this would mess up the desktop! On windows, the path remains the same for shells (cmd and powershell) and MSYS for that matter, as well as for the desktop or gui apps. The gui works fine on windows finding mingw installations added to the system PATH.

Comment: Non-interactive shell won't read some of the initialization scripts. And it would mess up the desktop because many processes become nonfunctional without a usable PATH, and to make your command-line (i.e. interactive) shell "forward" its path to the desktop environment, the desktop elements (dock, finder/konqueror, etc.) would have all to use path from `.bash_profile` and similar files. And any mistakes there would break it all. As it stands, if you mess up `.bash_profile`, only the interactive shell has diminished functionality. But at least you can open the terminal window to access it!

Comment: Required reading: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html

Comment: On Windows, the path indeed remains nominally same, because it's a registry setting and is afforded some care. Shell profile scripts do a bit more than merely setting path (well, they can do anything, indeed), so tying their correctness to whether your desktop environment works as a whole would be a liability. MSYS also reads `.bash_profile`, `.bash_rc`, and if those modify the path then again: the path seen from msys `bash` will be different then path seen from `cmd`. The path you claim is wrong is "wrong" for all applications started from the gui, not only Qt ones. And that's by design.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to add this info.